# is that possible to use shared memory for fftw?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-management, fftw

I have a numerical computation problem implemented with fourier transformation. I am using fftw to implement the FFT but the signal being FFTed is pretty strange. Half of the signal is from one array and the other half if from other array. In current code, I simply copy the data

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <complex>
#include <fftw3.h>

using namespace std;

void main(void)
{
  std::vector< std::complex<double> > V1(4);
  std::vector< std::complex<double> > V2(4);
  std::vector< std::complex<double> > V(8);

  for (int i=0; i<4; i++) V[i] = V1[i] = std::complex<double>(i, i);
  for (int i=0; i<4; i++) V[i+4] = V2[i] = std::complex<double>(i+4, i+4);

  fftw_complex* in = reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(&V[0]);
  fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(8, in, in, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_MEASURE);
  fftw_execute(plan);
}
```

This code works pretty well. But I would like to have big array refer to V1 and V2 instead of copying the data. I try the following code but it doesn't work, it is saying the the input array is ** (double pointer?)

```
std::vector< std::complex<double> > V1(4);
std::vector< std::complex<double> > V2(4);
fftw_complex *in[8];
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) in[i] = reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(&V1[i]);
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) in[i+4] = reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(&V2[i]);

for (int i=0; i<4; i++) V1[i] = std::complex<double>(i, i);
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) V2[i] = std::complex<double>(i+4, i+4);

fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(8, in, in, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_MEASURE);
fftw_execute(plan);
```

Is that anyway to make the "reference" array as the input of fftw? What happen for 2d array, is that possible to have the input array of 2d-fftw refer to two separate 2d array?

Comment: How are you data being entered? Can you construct one vector first than the other? What I want to ask is: are your resposability to construct V1 and V2?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to take two separate vector objects:

```
vector<fftw_complex> V1, V2;
```

and combine their respective contents to form another

```
vector<fftw_complex> V;
```

without any copying. This is impossible, because the memory occupied by `V1` and `V2` together is not contiguous. The memory occupied by `V`(as for any `vector`) is required to be contiguous, however. If you want to avoid copying in the example you gave, you could do it by using pointers, like this:

```
void main(void)
{
    std::complex<double>* V1;
    std::complex<double>* V2;
    std::vector< std::complex<double> > V(8);

    V1=&V[0];V2=&V[4];

    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) V1[i] = std::complex<double>(i, i);
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) V2[i] = std::complex<double>(i+4, i+4);

    fftw_complex* in = reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(&V[0]);
    fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(8, in, in, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_MEASURE);
    fftw_execute(plan);
 }
```

Of course this might or might not be feasible in your program.
Your second code segment has a major problem:

```
fftw_complex *in[8];
```

defines an array of 8 pointers to complex numbers, not an array of 8 complex numbers, so it won't fit as an input to `fftw_plan_dft_1d` and even if it did, the result would make no sense,
because you are feeding it a sequence of memory addresses instead of your data.

Comment: Thanks. I got the point. But unfortunately, the array are returned by other code and it is of std::vector, I cannot make it to pointer :(